# SwiftUI Multiple Select In ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I' m working on the project that needs to loop through the local JSON file like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsJ8r.png

How can I select each from each step, here is the repo https://github.com/siyayang0420/Jhin-Build.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but it's difficult to tell what's being asked here.

Comment: Can you ask a specific question, to a specific problem?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my question is to be able to single select from each step(there are 3 of them in the example), but the problem was I could only select one among all three steps. Thank you for trying to help, and the problem right now is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again for the confusing question, the problem is solved.
which can only select one single item in the whole list, but the problem is, there are 3 steps, What I wanted to do was be able to select one single item in each step, and what I did was changed I changed this (in the BuildRow.swift)

```
@Bingding var selected: String
```

to this

```
@Binding var selectedStrings : [String : String]
```

and

```
self.selected = buildItem
```

to this

```
self.selectedStrings[self.buildOption.steps] = buildItem
```

and in the BuildList.swfit, change to this:

```
@State var selectedString = ["" : ""]
```

Hope this can help people who need this

[Here is the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS9Nz.png)